# How to supply an Initial Value of the Text variable into a Text Widget Flutter

Tags: flutter

Into the circleAvatar from flutter before user put they own image I want to replace the space with the Initial value the first digit of the currentUser variable name into TextWidget.
it means for example the Name is "john" I want to get "J"
how we can reach that?

```
  
  final imageUrl = true;
```

and build method

```
imageUrl ? CircleAvatar(
                radius: 60,
                backgroundImage: AssetImage(currentUser.imageUrl),)
                  : CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
                child: Text(currentUser.name[0]),),
              SizedBox(
                height: 60,
              ),
```

In this way I get it but I dont know how to if imageUrl is null return currentUser.name[0]

Comment: please provide more information or code

Comment: I have edited the question I want to get the first digit of the text variable, if the name is John I want to get J

Answer (score 1):

to get the first character of a name:

```dart
final s = "John";
print(s[0]); // => J
```

to guard against null, you can use the `??` or the `?` operator.

to get a circle avatar with a character text widget as child instead of an image, depending on whether `imageUrl` is `null` or not:

```dart
imageUrl ? CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: NetworkImage(imageUrl),)
 : CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.brown.shade800,
    child: Text(currentUser && currentUser.isNotEmpty? currentUser[0] : "default"),)
```

Comment: I meant initialValue of the Text Variable for example the first digit on the name.

Comment: to get the first character of a string variable `s` just use `s[0]`, provided you know s is not empty

Comment: i added:
bool imageUrl = false;
  final s = "${currentUser.name}";
and the code:
imageUrl ? CircleAvatar(
                radius: 60,
                backgroundImage: AssetImage(currentUser.imageUrl),)
                  : CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
                child: Text(
                    currentUser.name.isEmpty && currentUser.name.isNotEmpty? s[0] : "default"),),
Image on circeavatar showing corrently but if I remove image the Initial value of the variable currentUser.name is not showing.
I added the code above

Comment: `imageUrl` does not need to be a `bool`. a `String` (url) will also do. when `imageUrl` is null, it will be treated like `false` would. Your edited question is still confusing though. You can either use the code in a method returning a `String` or in a method returning a `Widget` (a build method f.e.). A method returning once a `Widget` and once a `String` is not rly helpful. In either case, you might wanna use `if` and `else` instead of `?` and `:`, if this is confusing for you.